# Error in comparing two std::chrono::time_point instances

Tags: c++, datetime, c++11, std, c++-chrono

I have two std::chrono::time_point instances in variables `exp` and `time`. `exp` has a time in the future and `time` is the current time. But when I compare them as in this snippet:

```
std::time_t t_exp = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(exp);
std::time_t t_time = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(time);
std::cout << std::ctime(&t_exp) << std::ctime(&t_time) << (time > exp) << std::endl;
```

I get output:

```
Sat Apr 26 01:39:43 4758
Fri May 29 18:11:59 2020
1
```

Which is wrong because `exp` is in the year 4758 and `time` is in the year 2020.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What is the value of `t_exp`?

Comment: @HowardHinnant it's `-4243023785`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `t_exp` is `-4243023785`

This value of `time_t` corresponds to 1835-07-18 22:16:55 (assuming the Unix epoch and a precision of seconds, neither of which are specified by the standard, but are common).

Apparently the implementation of `ctime` on your platform can't handle dates this far in the past, which is a little surprising as 1835 is not very far in the past.

The value of `exp` is `-4243023785` times a million or a billion (depending on the precision of `system_clock` on your platform) and is stored with a signed 64 bit integer (there is no overflow).  Thus `time > exp == 1` is correct (`time` is `1590775919s` converted to the precision of `system_clock`).

Sat Apr 26 01:39:43 4758 corresponds to a `time_t` of 87990716383.

I see nothing wrong with your use of the `chrono` library in the above code.

**Update**

> The value 87990716383 is being converted to a `time_point` using `from_time_t()`

Ah, this combined with the knowledge that on your platform the precision of `system_clock` is `nanoseconds` tells me that you are experiencing overflow on the construction of `exp`.

This is not the code you have:

```
std::time_t t_exp = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(exp);
std::time_t t_time = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(time);
std::cout << std::ctime(&t_exp) << std::ctime(&t_time) << (time > exp) << std::endl;
```

The code you have looks something like:

```
// ...
std::time_t t_exp = 87990716383;
auto exp = std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(t_exp);
std::cout << std::ctime(&t_exp) << std::ctime(&t_time) << (time > exp) << std::endl;
```

On your platform, `system_clock` stores `nanoseconds` since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC in a signed 64 bit integer.  The maximum storable date (`system_clock::time_point::max()`) on your platform is:

```
2262-04-11 23:47:16.854775807
```

Beyond this, the underlying storage of `nanoseconds` overflows.

When 87990716383 (seconds) is converted in `from_time_t`, it is multiplied by a billion which overflows.  The overflowed value is -4243003985547758080 which corresponds to the date 1835-07-19 03:46:54.452241920.

You can get a larger range by using a coarser precision, for example:

```
std::time_t t_exp = 87990716383;
time_point<system_clock, microseconds> exp{seconds{t_exp}};
// exp == 4758-04-26 01:39:43.000000
```

Comment: I want chrono to interpret the time as in the future. The value 87990716383 is being converted to a `time_point` using `from_time_t()` and then compared to current `time_point`. Is there anyway to make it compare correctly.

Comment: What are these two values:  `exp.time_since_epoch().count()` and `time.time_since_epoch().count()`?

Comment: `-4243023785547758080`, `1590846692178289970` respectively.

Comment: All `time > exp` is doing is returning  `1590846692178289970 > -4243023785547758080`.